# Can I move to another hard drive whitout reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, hard-drive, re-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move Ubuntu installation from one hdd to another?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106527/how-to-move-ubuntu-installation-from-one-hdd-to-another)

My HDD memory is 80GB but I have another 300GB HDD.
Can I copy all files from 80GB to 300GB and than will it work good like working now.
Or if there another way to do this.
Thanks.