# Running out of space on hard drive, want to upgrade to ssd

Tags: 10.04

I'm currently receiving the low disk space message on Ubuntu 10.04 and would like to upgrade to an SSD for speed and size.  What is the best way to save my current information and change the disk and possibly the OS?

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided in this question: [How to move Ubuntu installation from one hdd to another?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106527/how-to-move-ubuntu-installation-from-one-hdd-to-another) may be useful for you. Of which I will reproduce here my own answer for your convenience.

> **[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)** may be useful for cloning your hard disk, even for those situations on which you need to do it with different size disks
>   as mentioned here:
>   http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-clone-hard-drives-clonezilla
>
> [image]
>
> > ## Moving to a bigger disk
> >
> > It's easy to ensure that a clone of a SCSI
> >     disk is restored to a SCSI disk, but you'll have a tough time finding
> >     an exact replica size-wise. The good news is you don't have to restore
> >     a disk on another disk of the same size. The even better news is that
> >     you can in fact restore the image to a much larger disk.
> >
> > When restoring a disk, Clonezilla enables you to resize the filesystem
> >     and create partitions on the new disk proportionally. But even if you
> >     are moving to a bigger disk, you might prefer to keep the partitions
> >     as they are. In that case you can ask Clonezilla to create the
> >     partition table as its listed in the image.
>
> There is documentation about moving to a larger disk as mentioned here
>   but I am not sure that you can do it the opposite (cloning to a
>   smaller disk).
>
> However, it's worth to try. Clonezilla offers several Live CD's and
>   bootable USB images and there is also documented that you can resize
>   the free space on the disk after the copy, in which case the
>   suggestion by @maniat1k to use gparted is also a good idea.
>
> If you use clonezilla, I would appreciate if you drop comments with
>   your experiences over here in order to have well documented how does
>   this work for future reference.

I hope this help you.

Good luck!