# Remastersys Alternative

Tags: backup, system-installation, remastersys

I was using remastersys on 12.04 to backup all my programs and settings and in that way, i was able to install it on many systems.

Now I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I added Precise deb PPA to software sources. Synaptic told me to downgrade some packages. SHould I do it or avoid it?

Other programs like  Relinux, UCK, Manual options doesn't suit me. I am looking for a straight forward method like Remastersys.

One option I found is Debian Builder but it is not available for 14.04 , I didn;t try Black Lab Image creator and there is no GUI for it.

Anybody please suggest me a effective, easy way to back all my settings and packages, so I don't need to download them again and again,

APT ON CD is still available??

Comment: Try the new one here: https://github.com/nerun/remastersys

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/looking-for-a-free-usable-alternative-for-remastersys/88186#88186

Comment: @social nerun's remastersys has been archived by the author on 2021-01-07. Just before the license was changed (GPLv2 to GPLv3), which is odd to me.

Comment: @social [nerun](https://github.com/nerun/remastersys)'s remastersys has been archived by the author on 2024-01-07. Just before the license was changed (GPLv2 to GPLv3), which is odd to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got remastersys CLI working in 14.04 LTS, Actually I copied files of Remastersys 12.04 version which were in

/etc/remastersys and /etc/remastersys.conf to same directory of 14.04 INstallation

and /usr/bin/remastersys , /usr/bin/remastersys-skelcopy to respective directory.

Installed dependcies, as suggested by FORK of remastersys, Black Lab Imager, but for some reason, black lab imager didn't worked for me. It generated final ISO images but when i tested it in virtual machine. There was kernel panic not syncing.

Method suggested for Remastersys fork, applied on Remastersys and it worked flawlessly for me.

Be sure to Install package discover, there is no package discover1 in repo.

More information can be get from Black Lab Image creator

http://system-imaging.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else needs help. This software does the job and more 'systemback'

http://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback/

You dont need to install remastersys or pay for Black Lab Image creator. It's a very well design application and works great on 14.04

To install, open the terminal and do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

Answer (score 2):

Distroshare Ubuntu Imager is a new script that I developed to replace Remastersys and Black Lab Image Creator: https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager . It is based on this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall, but includes some bug fixes and extras.

Answer (score 2):

Since the unfortunate withdrawal of the Remastersys developer, the web site http://www.remastersys.com now seems to have disappeared permanently, so it's not obvious how to get and use this excellent application.

Below is what I did to get a copy of Remastersys 3.0.4 running on Ubuntu 14.04. Note that the application development ended before U 14.04 so it is not necessarily fully tested on that version of Ubuntu. Caveat emptor!

1. Go to this website:
   http://www.filewatcher.com
2. Search for, then download the following files:

   remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb

   remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb (32 bit)

   remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb (64 bit)
3. Install as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb (32 bit)
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd_64.deb (64 bit)
   ```
4. If you have un-met dependencies run:

   `sudo apt-get -f install`
5. Launch Remastersys as follows:

   `sudo remastersys-gui`

This will bring up the usual Remastersys GUI menu.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

MintBackup seems to be a good solution. This tool comes with Linux Mint as a way to back up your files, directories, and packages. Since your settings are generally contained in your home directory, you could tell it to back that up, then later restore it. Then, all your settings would be preserved as well.

You can find information on installing the application [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/install-mintbackup-linux-mint-backup.html). Below are the commands you need to run in order to perform the installation.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/mintbackup && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintbackup
```

Once you've done that, you can open the application and configure your backup settings. Good luck!

Comment: this package is too old, my problem get resolved. I got remastersys  working on 14.04 and this will help me  atleast for 2 years.

Comment: this does not create a live installable Linux system... and is not close to the same thing.