# Need to move my whole lubuntu encrypted session to another drive

Tags: lubuntu, home-directory

Some simple questions:
Do I need to format the huayra partition?
Do I have to install the same lubuntu version and then move the session?
What is the best software to move my whole session, installed apps, media, etc?

Hi, I'm sure this is gonna be a "simple" question. I have 2 notebooks.
Net1 uses a 160gb drive, it has lubuntu and a windows XP which I don't use it but I never end up deleting either. 
Net2 has 250gb drive, same hardware, but has a custom version of linux called huayra or something, and a windows 7 that I can and probably will use.

The thing is I always use lubuntu cause it handles everything better, but the drive in net1 has started failing, so I want to move the WHOLE lubuntu to the 250gb drive, deleting the huayra linux.

I'm sure I can re-do the grub so I can boot windows 7 again but.. how do I "clone" my lubuntu session to the other drive?

USB? Network? Cloud? I think of cloning the disk but the sizes aren't the same so I don't think thats going to work, not only that but the windows 7 part I'm afraid to lose.

I can link them through a wireless network, connect the drives from USB.

I use the full encryption linux provides and I don't think I can "see" the files from another linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move Ubuntu installation from one hdd to another?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106527/how-to-move-ubuntu-installation-from-one-hdd-to-another) – should work with encryption too since the boot partition with Grub is not encrypted and you'll need to repair/re-install Grub anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
http://clonezilla.org/
I'm not sure that it can be done without the intervention of an external disk that acts as an intermediary

Comment: ill try clonezilla and then ill post if worked or not, cause like i said, the disk is kinda broken, so might bump into errors, wheter random or by stress on the tasks. or read issues with broken sector.